# How to show an animated image in starting of application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, animation

I am developing an application for client. 
In my application there is a requirement that when the application will start, firstly an animation should occur for some time then real application(view of application) should start.

But I don't know from where I should start and what code and where it should be write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it on

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Comment: ok, but what code should I write, Actually I want to display .gif file.

Comment: follow this link http://iphonedevelopertips.com/graphics/animated-gif-animated-images-iphone-style.html

Comment: I m in kolkata, but not bengali.

Comment: I have implemented through above link but in console window it is showing this message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil'

Comment: well...you are trying to work with an nil object from the array, i guess.

Comment: Actually, in this line [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame%d.jpg", i]]]; the error is coming. 0(zero) object is coming in imageArray. Is there any syntax error? I m following the same code of that link.

Comment: Is imageArray NSArray or NSMutableArray? Did you allocate that imageArray? please put some code snippet if you don't mind.

Comment: NSMutableArray. Need not to put any code. I just copy-paste the code  given in that link which u have given(http://iphonedevelopertips.com/graphics/animated-gif-animated-images-iphone-style.html).

Comment: Number of frames is as same for your application? please check yar IMAGE_COUNT (number of frames). Same code worked for me. I used it for splash screen.

Comment: That I have changed from 36 to 6(according to my requirement).

Comment: forget the loop. Just try NSMutableArray *imageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame1.jpg"],
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame2.jpg"],
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame3.jpg"],
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame4.jpg"],
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame5.jpg"],
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame6.jpg"],
          nil];

Comment: please check that you added those frames(images) to your local bundle and also the the file extension.

Comment: ok, definitely the images are added in resource folder with their extension, still in imageArray its showing 0 object.

Comment: And extension is jpg. okay you just add the images manually without using loop. just i mentioned earlier. then NSLog the imageArray.count.

Comment: yes,but this time in imageArray its showing 6 object on simulator only blank white screen  :(

Comment: little progress...but can't understand why not working. can you send me a dummy project to check it out? if u dont have any problem.

Comment: ya sure. but how will I send ?

Comment: send it to boneycse05@gmail.com

Comment: Plz check the mail, I have sent it.

Comment: check your mail...worked for me...

change the current ios of the app (mine is 4.2)

please be informed me whether its working or not...

Comment: ya its working!!! but as I have added this code in my project, its again showing only white screen :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot display an animated GIF in an iPhone application directly. What you should do is extract the individual frames of the animation from the GIF save them as PNG files and then use UIImageView animation to perform the actual animation. Have a look at [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/graphics/animated-gif-animated-images-iphone-style.html).

Also have a look at [this](http://www.computer-realm.net/how-split-animated-gifs-frames/) for a GIF splitter.

Comment: I have implemented through above link but in console window it is showing this message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil'

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that in RootViewController.
Keep a view called companyView and show images fading in or out as you wish.
You can do that in `viewDidAppear:`

Answer (score 0):

application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UIImage* image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.jpg"];
splashView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
[window addSubview:splashView];
[window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
[self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash) withObject:self afterDelay:2];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

-(void)removeSplash{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[splashView removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need to have your animation in video format and then use this [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html) to play it.

Comment: Actually I want to display .gif file not any media file.